# Relationships in the Datastore (One-to-Many)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was actually just wondering what the most efficient way to model a relationship of this kind would be in the google datastore.

Say I have 'Users' and 'Projects'. A project may have many users (One-to-Many). Is there a better way over modelling it like this?

```
class Users(ndb.Model):
    properties...

class Projects(ndb.Model):
    properties...

class UserToProject(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(Users)
    project = ndb.KeyProperty(Projects)
```

I'm looking at this from a 'normalization' standpoint, but I'm guessing there's probably a less costly way...

Comment: it depends on the use case. can you describe in what scenarios you need this data?

Comment: I'm definitely not a database expert, but lets say I have 100,000 projects and each project may have up to 100 users in them. Say I have 1,000,000 users for arguments sake. Would this hold up? (dumb numbers, but Im just curious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a many-to-many relationship as a project has many users and a user may be assigned to many projects (I assume).

Using NDB we can try to forget about traditional database relationships and focus on the objects themselves. The simplest way to represent this is to link a list of projects to a user:

```
class Project(ndb.Model):
    properties...

class User(ndb.Model):
    properties...
    projectKeys = Ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Project, repeated=True)
```

Now, when viewed from a user's perspective, we can simply retrieve all projects they belong to:

```
user = User.query(...).get()
projectKeys = user.projectKeys # you can retrieve these as required
```

When viewed from a project viewpoint, you can find linked users as follows:

```
project = Project.query(...).get()
users = User.query(User.projectKeys=project.key).fetch()
```

Caveat: Friday afternoon - untested code. Concepts should hopefully help though :)

Comment: You rock. I'll check it out! Its 2 am here so... Even though the coding blood in me is telling me to stay up, Im done for :/.

Comment: Just two questions. If users aren't part of a project, doesn't this mean that there will be space allocated in the rows for 'projectKeys'? It will be blank though, correct? And can KeyProperty store multiple keys?

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but if the projectKeys are not assigned on user, the row remains void of that value (you can check this in the datastore viewer) -ie: unassigned. That said, when you do the retrieve it will return an empty list, not a 'None' value. The 'repeated=True' indicates that the property is a list in this case. So yes, you can store multiple keys.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper Remember, Datastore is schemaless, so space doesn't get allocated for properties. You could have 2 entities of the same kind with completely different properties, if you wanted.

Comment: This approaches main limitation is the limit of keys you can store in the projectKeys Property.   I have a similiar project in the past, course, student and enrollment.  Students can be enrolled in multiple classes.  So we used an intermediate entity (Enrollment, that cached important parts of the student and course,)  which is how we retrieved the bulk of the info. We only went to the student or the course when we need more specific information about each end of the relationship. Ultimately data access patterns and use cases will dictate which is more appropriate.